# How to calculate shortest path using pgrouting 2.1?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, shortest-path

I installed postgresql 9.1.12 & created database "**mydb**" with user "**abc**" as below:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1 postgresql-9.1-contrib postgresql-9.1-postgis and created databse "mydb". Then extended the mydb using

psql -h localhost -d mydb -U abc -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql

psql -h localhost -d mydb -U abc -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/postgis-1.5/spatial_ref_sys.sql
```

Then installed pgrouting to "**mydb**" in my **ubuntu 12.04** machine after downloading .deb file using:

```
sudo dpkg -i Downloads/postgresql-9.1-pgrouting_2.1.0-ppa1~precise1_i386.deb

psql -h localhost -d mydb -U abc -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/pgrouting--2.1.0.sql
```

How to calculate shortest path of table "**roads**" ?
I tried this https://anitagraser.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/ but the function `shortest_path` is not working.

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rsFw.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rsFw.jpg)[![This code works on Postgre 14.3, Thank You Very Much given samples !!!!!!!!!
](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT9wY.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT9wY.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

try dijsktra algorithm:

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('
    SELECT id,
         source,
         target,
         cost,
         reverse_cost
        FROM ways',
    15, 
    16, 
    directed := true)
```

- **source and target** - columns which represent id of vertices
- **cost and reverse cost** - cost of edges for calculate shortest path. you can use cost for time for fastest path or lentg of edges for shortest path
- **15, 16** - some numbers, ending vertices of your path
- **directed** - true for directed graph, false for undirected

If you want shortest path replace cost and reverse_cost column with `st_length(geometry_column)`

Keep in mind this function you can use only for network topology. I does not, use pgr_createTopology function. More informations you can find here: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.1.0-dev/en/index.html